# How to fix peeling paint above register?

Tags: painting, repainting

I have some peeling paint above a register. I suspect it's due to curtains hanging over it and causing too much heat on the wall but I'm no expert.

I scraped all the loose paint. How should I proceed before repainting?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could we have a shot from a bit further away as well, I cant tell what we are looking at